# JMeter override hosts / DNS

Tags: dns, jmeter, vhosts, hosts

In JMeter, is it possible to override the hosts file somehow?
I mean something that is described here: https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420205-Hosts-Override

What I want to test:
Behind a Loadbalancer there are many application servers (Apache webservers). The app-servers host different sites via vhosts. They are requested by customers via the loadbalancer. Thehe loadbalancer sends the requests to the app-servers. Based on the url the webserver 'knows' which site is requested.

Now I want to send requests directly to the webservers. I could change my hosts file, so a request will bypass the Loadbalancer. but I want to test different webservers at the same time. So I would need a separate Hosts file for every thread group.

Comment: why do you want to change it in the middle of the run? wouldn't it be simpler to put all servers behind LB in your hosts file before run, and then just target them (instead of LB name) during run?

Comment: I have a lot of servers and I want to send requests to all the servers separately. I want to bypass the loadbalancer. But on all servers I need to use the same hostname since they can only be reached via the vhosts configuration.
that is why I want a function like the one I linked to (in blazemeter), because I want to be able to test all server from one loadgenerator (JMeter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the element DNS cache Manager:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager

This allows you to associate a host with different IPs

It also allows you to use different DNS servers.